# Sumif formula based on background color of adjacent cell

Tags: excel, background-color, sumifs, vba

I was wondering if there is a Sumif formula that will sum all the values in Column B based on whether or not the cell next to it in Column A is highlighted.

An example is the cells in A3 and A8 are highlighted yellow so I want the sum of the cells in B3 and B8 to go in F4. Is there a formula, or macro that I have to create to accomplish this?

Comment: No formula directly and you will need to write the vba.  Are these cells conditionally formatted to become highlighted?  Is so, what is the rule?

Comment: Echoing @ScottCraner here. Here's a fairly comprehensive guide to summing/counting by color (https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/12/count-sum-by-color-excel/). Also as he pointed out, if the highlighting is coming from a conditional highlighting rule, you can just highlight the conditional highlighting rule and SUMIF based on that (it's more staightforward than tackling the highlighting approach in that case).

Comment: The color is coming from a Macro from a search, which is from this website: http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/forum/helproom-1/excel-2003-help-how-highlight-search-resukts-305437/

Comment: Then in that code keep a running total of the cells as they are highlighted using offset and put the answer in the desired cell when complete.

Comment: I'm not familiar with offset, especially in conjunction with coding. Could you provide me with an example or a resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a VBA function to sum all cells that are colored:
[image]

Code:

```
Public Function ColorSum(myRange As Range) As Variant

Dim rngCell As Range
Dim total As Variant

For Each rngCell In myRange.Cells

    If rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142 Then
    total = total + rngCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If

Next rngCell

ColorSum = total

End Function
```